# Adding a new route to yeoman angular-fullstack breaks it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I am currently working on the following FreeCodeCamp challenge:
http://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/basejump-build-a-voting-app.

After the user is logged in, I want to redirect them to a certain page. As a result, I make a new route, via the yeoman angular-fullstack command:

```
>> yo angular-fullstack:route wall
```

After doing so, I update the newpage.controller.js to include $http, like so:

```
angular.module('votingAppApp')
  .controller('WallCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  });
```

When I run grunt serve, the page is blank and in Console.Log, I get the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module votingAppApp due to: 
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider
```

Can anyone give me a tip as to what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

Update: I think the issue at hand may be due to the fact that I am using uiRouter, instead of ngRoute. If that is the case, how would I mitigate this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe only angular Route is installed try to install [angular.ui.router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)
it may be the problem.

if it's installed already don't forget:

```
$routeProvider is for ngRoute

$urlRouterProvider is for ui-router
```

Comment: Looks like I was using routeProvider for ui-router. Thanks!